# DivExpress Spell checker with more than one languages

Tags: devexpress

I need to check both english and Greek words. I used SpellCheckerOpenOfficeDictionary to add the English and greek dictionary. But it is not working

```
Public Sub SpellCheckSettings(ByRef objSpellChecker As SpellChecker)
    Dim objDictionary, objGreekdic As SpellCheckerOpenOfficeDictionary
    Dim objCulture, objGreekCulture As CultureInfo

    Try
        objCulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
        objSpellChecker.Culture = objCulture
        objDictionary = New SpellCheckerOpenOfficeDictionary(GetLanguageDictionaryPath("en_US.dic"), GetLanguageDictionaryPath("en_US.aff"), objCulture)
        objSpellChecker.Dictionaries.Add(objDictionary)


        objGreekCulture = New CultureInfo("el")
        objGreekdic = New SpellCheckerOpenOfficeDictionary(GetLanguageDictionaryPath("el_GR.dic"), GetLanguageDictionaryPath("el_GR.aff"), objGreekCulture)
        objSpellChecker.Dictionaries.Add(objGreekdic)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

IF I use either of the above the spell check works perfectly. Any one please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the SpellChecker's Culture to the Invariant value.  In this case, the spellChecker will use both dictionaries to check words and calc suggestions.  You can set the spellChecker's Culture using the following code:

```
        spellChecker1.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: Could you please help how to set the invariant culture